# Balls and Bins problem max size of bin

Tags: random-variables, random

I need to make a program which satisfies the below (my question is not about code):

> The Balls’n Bins-problem deals with the experiment of randomly distributing a number of balls into an equal number of bins and trying to figure out how many balls there should be room for in each bin in order to avoid overflow with very high probability.

So I need to:

- Have N balls
- Have the same amount of bins as balls, so same as N
- Figure out how much room there should be in each bin to avoid overflow
- Each ball is distributed randomly in a bin

The thing I don't get is, shouldn't the size of all bins just be the same as amount of balls, which means you will never get overflow? If we got 10 balls, we just make all bins 10 in size?

Example:

> What is the maximum number of balls in a bin if 10,007 balls are randomly distributed in an equal number of bins? You may wish to calculate an average and a maximum value over several experiments.

Comment: If you need to store information about each ball in a bin, then you have to be prepared for the possibility that all the balls (10 in your example) may go into a single bin.  If you're just counting the number of balls, then all you need is one integer per bin, of course.

Comment: Example question:
What is the maximum number of balls in a bin if 10,007 balls are randomly distributed in an equal number of bins?

Comment: I would say the max number is 10,007, which is the same number of balls. But it just feels like this is not the correct answer (it can't be that easy).

Comment: In that case the maximum in one bin is 10,007, although it may be very unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer (for this exercise) is to just find the bin with the highest amount of balls, repeat the experiment N times (like one thousand times) and get the average of the one thousand highest numbers.